# How can I run an Android App with visual Studio and Xamarin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, emulation

I got a few issues when I try tu run my apps with visual studio and Xamarin, I have created a project and when the emulator shows up nothing happens. This is al I have... [image]

I hope you can help me, I have been trying to compile the projects for more than one week without results.

Comment: Do you see anything in the "Output" or "Lista de errores" window? What if you put a breakpoint on your first line of code? Is it reached?

Comment: There's nothing in there, even if I close the emulator window it just says Implementation error, and the "Output" is completely empty. I tried to put the breakpoint but it is not getting reached...

Comment: Does the app appear in the list of applications on the emulator? If not it sounds like it's not actually deploying to the device. Try setting the platform target to Any CPU